# Child fragment replacing parent fragment root layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've viewpager with 5 fragments, in one of them I want to completely replace it by button click. I also want to be able to hide child fragment by back button. 
Here this fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/contacts_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/import_contacts"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<include layout="@layout/listview_filter"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_my_clusters"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_wide_arrow_bg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/TEXT"
    android:text="@string/btn_my_clusters_text"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/contacts_list"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I try replace `contacts_layout` like this:

```
ImportContactsFragment importContactsFragment = new  ImportContactsFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.replace(R.id.contacts_layout, importContactsFragment).commit();
```

it doesn't work (I mean there is no error, but my ImportContactsFragment not showing at all). But when I try replace `import_contacts` view like this:

```
ImportContactsFragment importContactsFragment = new  ImportContactsFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.replace(R.id.import_contacts, importContactsFragment).commit();
```

everything is ok, ImportContactsFragment shown.

So I wonder is it possible to replace all fragment content by child fragment? Maybe I can do it in some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `replace` transaction doesn't remove the current views from the target layout container so when you use the first pice of code the new `Fragment` is added to the contacts_layout `LinearLayout` but it will not be seen as the previous views cover the entire screen(height).

With the second piece of code the `LinearLayout` to which you add the new `Fragment` is the first child of the parent `LinearLayout` and it has space so its visible.

For what you're doing I advise you to wrap the initial layout in a `Fragment` class placed in a wrapper layout which you could then later replace very easy.